# Account type not visible in Google API> Google Analytics configuration page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-api, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up **Universal Analytics** through **Google Tag Manager** in Magento 2.3.2.
I follow the official doc, or other tutorials, but in my backend, when I go to **`Store>Sales>Google API>Google Analytics`** and enable it, I have no dropdown Account Type. Any idea what I am missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up wrong for Google Tag Manager.

These option used for google analytics like UA-1344454

You can easily add GTM without third-party extensions. All you need is to add the GTM code to your active theme. The GTM code is divided into two parts: script and noscript.
You need to put the GTM snippet into these two phtml templates for head and body:

```
// YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_head.phtml
<script>..</script> <!-- GTM code -->

// YourTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml
<noscript>..</noscript> <!-- GTM code -->
```

To load the files correspondingly you should use the default .xml file:

```
    <!-- YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml -->
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.head" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_head.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

After GTM is added you can set up Google Analytics and other tools for tracking and reporting about website traffic.

Comment: Thank you, I might do that. However in the magento official tuto there is a Account Type dropdown in the configuration page which allows to select GTM and enter the tracking id. Is it only a Enterprise Edition feature ?

Comment: Yes its only Enterprise Edition feature provide this.